How to use all logical processor in an array job?
I am trying to run an array job in slurm with 2700 tasks. The computer I'm using has 48 physical cores, and 96 logical cores. However, when I run my script, every task is associated to 2 CPUs, instead of one. I've tried all sbatch and srun parameters which seemed to make sense, but I couldn't put 96 tasks to run in parallel. Here is my "small" script and the outputs:
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --array=0-199

seed=$((SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID % 10 + 1))
line=$((SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID / 10 + 1))
line=${line%%.*}

file=$(sed "${line}q;d" ./instances/small.txt)
output=${file#"instances/"}
output=${output%".dat"}

srun --output="out/${output}_${seed}.stdout.txt" ./a.out "${file}" out/ -seed
"${seed}" -t 1765

scontrol output:
NodeName=node04 Arch=x86_64 CoresPerSocket=24
   CPUAlloc=8 CPUTot=96 CPULoad=1.14
   AvailableFeatures=(null)
   ActiveFeatures=(null)
   Gres=gpu:3
   NodeAddr=node04 NodeHostName=node04 Version=19.05.5
   OS=Linux 5.4.0-196-generic #216-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 29 13:26:53 UTC 2024
   RealMemory=515624 AllocMem=114688 FreeMem=21583 Sockets=2 Boards=1
   State=MIXED ThreadsPerCore=2 TmpDisk=0 Weight=1 Owner=N/A MCS_label=N/A
   Partitions=networkcia
   BootTime=2024-09-28T15:29:38 SlurmdStartTime=2024-10-25T10:47:24
   CfgTRES=cpu=96,mem=515624M,billing=96
   AllocTRES=cpu=8,mem=112G
   CapWatts=n/a
   CurrentWatts=0 AveWatts=0
   ExtSensorsJoules=n/s ExtSensorsWatts=0 ExtSensorsTemp=n/s

And when I run:
  JOBID    PARTITION       NAME   USER ST       TIME  NODES CPUS
6304_[4   networkcia      small myuser PD       0:00      1 1
 6304_0   networkcia      small myuser  R       0:01      1 2
 6304_1   networkcia      small myuser  R       0:01      1 2
 6304_2   networkcia      small myuser  R       0:01      1 2
 6304_3   networkcia      small myuser  R       0:01      1 2
 6304_4   networkcia      small myuser  R       0:01      1 2
 6304_5   networkcia      small myuser  R       0:01      1 2
 6304_6   networkcia      small myuser  R       0:01      1 2
 6304_7   networkcia      small myuser  R       0:01      1 2
 6304_8   networkcia      small myuser  R       0:01      1 2
 6304_9   networkcia      small myuser  R       0:01      1 2
6304_10   networkcia      small myuser  R       0:01      1 2
6304_11   networkcia      small myuser  R       0:01      1 2
6304_12   networkcia      small myuser  R       0:01      1 2
6304_13   networkcia      small myuser  R       0:01      1 2
6304_14   networkcia      small myuser  R       0:01      1 2
6304_15   networkcia      small myuser  R       0:01      1 2
6304_16   networkcia      small myuser  R       0:01      1 2
6304_17   networkcia      small myuser  R       0:01      1 2
...

UPDATE (2024-10-30):
My current workaround is to run two tasks in background without srun:
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --array=0-99

seed1=$((SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID % 5 * 2 + 1))
seed1=$((seed1 + 1))
line=$((SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID / 5 + 1))
line=${line%%.*}

file=$(sed "${line}q;d" ./instances/small.txt)
output=${file#"instances/"}
output=${output%".dat"}

./a.out "${file}" out/ -seed "${seed1}" -t 1765 > "out/${output}_${seed1}.stdout.txt" &
./a.out "${file}" out/ -seed "${seed2}" -t 1765 > "out/${output}_${seed2}.stdout.txt" &
wait


You can try adding
#SBATCH --hint=multithread

to tell Slurm you want both hardware threads of a each CPU core to be available independently for the tasks.

I've tried this one, but each task in the job array still gets one node with two CPUs.

Ah yes in Slurm will always allocate full cores (both threads) to jobs so the --hint=multithread is useful in the case of multi-CPU jobs. For single-CPU jobs, you cannot achieve that unless you modify the Slurm configuration to force it to consider the node to have 96 CPUs rather than 48 2-threads CPUs
